# LazyInitializationException when converting Entities within Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-data

I have a problem to lazily load fields during the conversion of domain objects from the database into resource objects for the client.

- `Customer`:      Entity loaded from the database with lazy fields
- `FullCustomer`:  Entity that will be sent to the client.

**Service Layer:**

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Customer getById(Long id){
    return customerRepository.getById(id);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Autowired
private ResourceAssembler<Customer, FullCustomer> converter;

@RequestMapping(...)
public final FullCustomer getCustomerById(long cid) {
    Customer customer = customerService.getById(cid);
    return converter.convert(customer);
}
```

**Converter (`ResourceAssembler<Customer, FullCustomer>`)**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public FullCustomer convert(Customer input) {
    System.err.println("Is open: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());  //prints true

    FullCustomer fullCustomer = new FullCustomer();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(input, fullCustomer);  //Fails
    return fullCustomer;
}
```

So my controller uses a Converter to Transform the Database-Entity into an Entity for the Client. The transformation triggers the loading of other lazily loaded Entities.

**My Problem:** Although the convert function opens a new transaction (`Is open` prints `true)`, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: 
    Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: [..], could not initialize proxy - no Session (..); 
    nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ...
```

When accessing the lazily loaded fields before using BeanUtils, I get the following:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
    failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: [..], could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You load the customer from one transaction, and that transaction doesn't initialize the lazy loaded fields. That transaction is then committed and the associated Hibernate session is closed, making the customer entity detached. Then you start another transaction which tries initializing the lazy fields of the detached customer.

That can't work: You need to load the lazy fields from the same transaction as the one loading the customer. So

- make your controller method transactional, or
- initialize the lazy fields in getById(), or
- use a join fetch in the repository, to make sure the query loads the customer and the required associations, or
- make getById() return a FullCustomer
- use an OpenEntityManagerInView interceptor/filter (and make your converter non-transactional)

Comment: Is there a way to re-attach the existing entity? Loading the fields inside my Service layer is not an option and adding `@Transactional` to my Controller fails to create a Transaction.

Comment: No. You would have to reload the entity by its ID, making your service layer completely useless. A fifth option is to use an OpenEntityManagerInView interceptor/filter.